# Zingchart is not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean.io, zingchart

I'm working with the mean.io starter project and I am trying to get a chart to display using zingchart.
When I inspect my code, I see a zingchart not defined error that looks like this.

[image]

I am new to using mean.io.
I should also mention that this is taking place in a new package that I created called "dashboard"

Here is my controller (dashboard.js):

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  /* jshint -W098 */

  angular
    .module('mean.dashboard', ['zingchart-angularjs'])
    .controller('DashboardController', function($scope) {
      $scope.myJson = {
    type : 'line',
    series : [
      { values : [54,23,34,23,43] },
      { values : [10,15,16,20,40] }
      ]
};

});
})();
```

My html file (index.html):

```
<html ng-app="mean.dashboard" ng-init="checkCircle()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zingchart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zingchart-angularjs.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="DashboardController" ng-cloak layout="column">

    <!-- graph here -->
    <h1>Graph Test</h1>
    <div ng-controller="DashboardController">
    <div zingchart id="myChart" zc-json="myJson" zc-height=500 zc-width=600></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js file:

```
'use strict';

/*
 * Defining the Package
 */
var Module = require('meanio').Module;

var Dashboard = new Module('dashboard', ['zingchart-angularjs']);

/*
 * All MEAN packages require registration
 * Dependency injection is used to define required modules
 */

Dashboard.register(function(app, auth, database, circles) {

  //We enable routing. By default the Package Object is passed to the routes
  Dashboard.routes(app, auth, database, circles);

  //We are adding a link to the main menu for all authenticated users
  Dashboard.menus.add({
    title: 'dashboard',
    link: 'dashboard',
    roles: ['authenticated'],
    menu: 'main'
  });

  Dashboard.angularDependencies(['zingchart-angularjs']);

  return Dashboard;
  });
```

Comment: are you not using app.js?

Comment: are you talking about the project root app.js?

Comment: whatever you posted above

Comment: I believe I am using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this problem or one similar, I will post my answer.

Within the package/folder you want to add the zingchart dependency, or any dependency for that matter, you have to add it to your bower.json file like this.

```
{
  "name": "packagename",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "zingchart-angularjs": "latest" <!--dependency-->
  }
}
```

then in your app.js file you need to register the zingchart dependency like this

```
'use strict';

/*
 * Defining the Package
 */
var Module = require('meanio').Module;

var packagename= new Module('packagename');

/*
 * All MEAN packages require registration
 * Dependency injection is used to define required modules
 */

packagename.register(function(app, auth, database, circles) {

  //We enable routing. By default the Package Object is passed to the routes
  packagename.routes(app, auth, database, circles);

  //register dependencies
  packagename.angularDependencies(['zingchart-angularjs']);

  return packagename;
});
```

you then need to make sure the zingchart dependency library is inlcuded in this path /public/assets/lib and make sure that this path is correctly referenced in your .bowerrc file like this

```
{
  "directory": "public/assets/lib"
}
```

then you can proceed to add the code that creates and renders the actual chart in your controller.js file

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('mean.packagename', ['zingchart-angularjs'])
    .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
      $scope.myJson = {
    type : 'line',
    series : [
      { values : [54,23,34,23,43] },
      { values : [10,15,16,20,40] }
    ]
};

    });
})();
```

and finally, you can reference this code in your html file like this

```
<body ng-app="mean.dashboard">
  <div ng-controller="AppController" id="resizable">
    <div zingchart id="chart-1" zc-json="myJson" zc-width="100%" zc-height="100%"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code i see lot of issues, let me simplify your code and show the mistakes,

```
<html ng-app="mean.dashboard" ng-init="checkCircle()">
```

you cannot have ng-init with inside the html , it needs to be placed inside the body, also ng-controllers are duplicated. You need to have it only in one place.

Check the demo below

**Demo**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('mean.dashboard', ['zingchart-angularjs'])
    .controller('DashboardController', function($scope) {
      $scope.myJson = {
    type : 'line',
    series : [
      { values : [54,23,34,23,43] },
      { values : [10,15,16,20,40] }
    ]
};

    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/374756/zingchart-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/374756/zingchart-angularjs-1.0.4.js"></script>
<body ng-app="mean.dashboard">
  <div ng-controller="DashboardController" id="resizable">
    <div zingchart id="chart-1" zc-json="myJson" zc-width="100%" zc-height="100%"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, i appreciate you helping me with the above.  I changed my code to reflect your suggestions and I am still getting a 'zingchart is not defined error'.

Comment: check if your zingchart reference is loaded  properly in network tab

Comment: I actually dont see it in there. What steps should i take?

Comment: check if there is any error in console ( goto network tab and see)

Comment: yes there is. it is the same error i posted in the oringial question